# Merge/Join images & video files together using mencoder or ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, mencoder

Hi i have command to merge video files
but i want to join an image to a video file.

What i am doing:

1) convert image to mp4 using ffmpeg

2) joining this converted video to my selected video using mencoder

but it prommpts an error:
cannot mix video only files with audio-video files try -nosound.

i also added -nosound but with this the resultant file does not contains any audio.

what to do?

ffmpeg command:

```
-y -i Garden.jpg -s 640x480 converted.mp4
```

this converted .mp4 file is created properly but with no audio

mencoder command:

```
-oac mp3lame -ovc lavc -noodml -o output.mp4 converted.mp4 selected.mp4
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

If you target is Windows, converting the result to msmpeg4v2 (avi) or mpeg1video (mpg) or asf (wmv) would probably work best.

Note, ASF files often have .wmv or .wma extensions in Windows. It should also be mentioned that Microsoft claims a patent on the ASF format, and may sue or threaten users who create ASF files with non-Microsoft software. It is strongly advised to avoid ASF where possible.

[Read this for full list](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC9).

Comment: Shimmy i cldnt understand the answer.Do u mean to say that instead of using mpg i should use some other container format say "wmv" that is supported on windows.i tried that too. I converted avi files to wmv and then tried to merge them but still the output plays well on vlc but when i play on media player on content belonging to firts file gets played but content of second file is not palyed.

Comment: I added a note that wmv is less recommended than avi or mpeg. Anyway, make sure it's converted to msmpeg4v2 or mpeg1video (follow the [link](http://goo.gl/eRXBC) in my post) before merging, then do the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free command line tool which can join MPEG 1 files:

http://mpgtx.sourceforge.net/#Download

(Windows exe available). Did not try it on my own, however.

EDIT: another alternative may be to utilize VirtualDub. You have to write your merge command to a script and pass the script name per command line:

http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=20

However, you have to get yourself through the syntax of the scripting language

http://www.virtualdub.org/docs/vdscript.txt

(I did not try this by myself programmatically, have only used virtual dub via GUI interface to concat video files, which worked really well.)

Comment: Doc i tried this tool but i found that when i played the resultant file in windows media player then audio of second file came before the video and when i tested on vlc then i found that first video stopped and after sometime second video started means a gap exists

Comment: @Swati: added another alternative

Comment: Thank u Doc i have seen that but cannot understand how to compile virtual dub via c#.everywhere i found code in vc++.

Comment: Compile??? Perhaps you got me wrong. Use VirtualDub just like `ffmpeg` as a command line tool, running it via `Process.Start`

Comment: still finding the commands to get the work done via VirtualDub.Do u have any list that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) can accomplish this easily with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i vid-1.mp4 -i vid-2.mp4 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -ac 1 -c:a libmp3lame -filter_complex '[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' output.mp4
```

Comment: but your example only showing joining mp4 video formats not image sequence .